# Bulk Insert incrementing IDs on a varchar ID field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

If I run a query like this:

```
insert into table (unique_id, column) 
select 
(isnull(max(cast(unique_id as int)), 1) + 1 from table) as id, 
another_column
from another_table
```

the unique_id field always comes out as 1 and doesn't increment. Is there a way to have this increment whilst doing the insert?

p.s This is a simple version of what I am doing but the example is accurate

Edit: SQL Server 2008

Thanks

Comment: Seriously: just use an `INT IDENTITY` column - that'll save you **sooo much hassle** and grief which is totally not worth it.

Comment: This is a 10 year old program with about 200 tables in. Although I would prefer it, it's not possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use identity(mssql), auto_increment(mysql) or sequences (psql/oracle/any other proper DB).

Comment: I know I can use identity but I wanted to see if it is possible in line with my SQL?

Comment: @webnoob I don't think you can do it in your way. The `max(unique_id)` (and any other similar expressions) is calculated once, before inserting any data. This is how it must work, you cannot change it.

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

For mssql 2005+

```
insert into [table] (unique_id, [column])  
select  row_number() over (order by another_column) as id,  
another_column from another_table
```

or

```
insert into [table] (unique_id, [column])  
select  row_number() over (order by newid()) as id,  
another_column from another_table
```

Comment: What would happen if the table already had values in with ID's though? Wouldn't I end up with duplicate IDs?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function.

```
INSERT INTO [table] (unique_id, [column])
SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY another_column ) AS id,
            another_column
FROM        another_table
```

Here's [a working example that you can play with](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63837/row-number-example).

**Note:** This does not ensure that the ID you're generating using `ROW_NUMBER()` is unique within the table that you're inserting into.

Comment: What would happen if the table already had values in with ID's though? Wouldn't I end up with duplicate IDs?

Comment: Yes, it would certainly duplicate the ID's (or generate an error based on a constraint).

Comment: Ok, looks like I need to use Identity then. Thanks.